# The game that was previously working says 'it is not compatible with my device' after factory reset

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, factory-reset

I factory reset my Acer Liquid z160 Android phone because it was getting laggy and can't open some apps. Now it is fixed. But I now have a new problem. This game I was playing for months on this phone, says it is not compatible with my phone. I still have the files of the game in my SDcard but app isn't there. I tried to update my phone but it says it is already up-to-date (4.2.2) What should I do?

Comment: Try to give a more clear title to your question.

Comment: Did you try to download the game again? All apps which you installed would have been wiped after factory reset

Comment: Yes I have .. But it won't let me. It says its not compatible with my phone.also the game was installed in my sd card before I reset it which I remove before the reset.

Answer (score 2):

Simply find .apk file of that game on google, and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before. It means that you can not play the game in question due to incompatibles like if your device does not support multi-touch and the feature is then recommended for use in the game. If you have another device that you can play this on you can extract the app (50 / 50 chance). Some apps can be extracted others can not. You will in turn have to allow **Unknown Sources**(Risky for leaving on when done and otherwise) when you are to reinstall it. I have done this with a game, to play on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 that said "this device is not supported". You'll need to download an APK extractor first (APK: Android PacKage)
**WARNING: Sharing Applications Purchased by you (Free and or otherwise) is against Google Play's terms and conditions and or is in a grey area. Selling the app as your own WILL put your Google account under review for possible ban and or removal**

- Grey area
   -Open Source Hardware (**Recommend to ask Developer** Developer will recommend you to direct him/her to the app on his/her device and install)

After installing the APK extractor do as follows

- find the app in question
- extract
- locate APK
- Save to SD card and place into device of choosing
- go to settings on device in question
- go to Security
- Allow Unknown Sources (**Read Warning and continue at own risk**)
- goto folder with game in question
- click the APK and install
- done